# Python how to get bound method of some property.setter

Tags: python, properties, attributes, python-descriptors

I have a class with one `property`.  I also have a setter for that property.  How can I get the bound method for the `property.setter`?

---

**Why I'm Asking**

With normal methods, this is easy.  One can just use `class_instance.method_name`.

However, I'm having a tough time figuring this out for `property`, since it returns a descriptor object.

---

**Example Code**

This was written with `Python 3.6`:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._some_attr = 0

    @property
    def some_attr(self) -> int:
        return self._some_attr

    # How can I get this bound method?
    @some_attr.setter
    def some_attr(self, val: int) -> None:
        self._some_attr = val

    def normal_method(self, val: int) -> None:
        self.some_attr = val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_class = SomeClass()
    print(some_class.some_attr)  # prints: 0
    print(some_class.normal_method)  # prints: bound method SomeClass.normal_method
```

Comment: There's no great way to do this, since no actual bound-method is created. You'd have to essentially partially apply the setter, retrieved from the class, with the instance yourself. So `lambda v: SomeClass.some_attr.__set__(some_class, v)` for example...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga!  I am going to open a bounty to see if there's a different way.  Feel free to answer!

Comment: Given juanpa.arrivillaga's comment, what exactly would you want? Something assigned to `f` so that `f(v)` performs the assignment `some_class.some_attr = v`?

Comment: Yes @chepner, sorry for being vague.  Is there some way to get the signature of `some_attr`'s setter using `inspect.signature`?  Running `inspect.signature(SomeClass.some_attr.__set__)` yields `<Signature (instance, value, /)>`, which is the signature for a generic `__set__`.  How can I get it to sort of match a non-property, `inspect.signature(some_class.normal_method)`?

Comment: I realize we are now off topic from the question, I will rename question to match if this goes somewhere

Comment: the main answer to this XY problem is: why do you need that? what is an actual meaning of getting bound-property-setter?

Comment: Hi @AzatIbrakov, thank you for trying to help.  I think, to provide more details, would have made things much more confusing.  I found the given answer to be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of Python [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties), you can find the equivalent implementation of the `property` descriptor in pure Python, where the setter method simply calls the unbound method with the given object and target value:

```
def __set__(self, obj, value):
    if self.fset is None:
        raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
    self.fset(obj, value) # unbound method called
```

In other words, no bound method is actually created when you use the property setter, so there is no way to "get" the bound method when it does not actually exist.

However, you can create such a bound method of a given instance for a given unbound method, in this case the setter attribute of the `property` descriptor, `SomeClass.some_attr.fset`, using the `types.MethodType` constructor:

```
from types import MethodType

some_class = SomeClass()
f = MethodType(SomeClass.some_attr.fset, some_class)
print(f)
f(2) # calls the bound setter method, equivalent to: some_class.some_attr = 2
print(some_class.some_attr)
```

This outputs:

```
<bound method SomeClass.some_attr of <__main__.SomeClass object at 0x0000015C3CCB74C0>>
2
```

Comment: Thank you @blhsing for putting the explanations, that helped a lot in my understanding.

Comment: You're welcome. There is indeed no usage information of `types.MethodType` in the documentation of the `types` module; however, its usage is actually demonstrated in the documentation of descriptor when it details how bound methods are created as a descriptor getter with equivalent Python code: https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods